# a list like structure in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am looking to implement a simple data structure, something like a linked list but I don't need anything that complicated yet, or do I?

Let's say I have a book data structure.

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    size_t number;
} book;
```

I'd like to append these to a growing list of books which in memory should look like this.

```
------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ......
------------------------
```

since I am not doing anything fancy except adding a bunch of books and never changing the order and only free the books at the end of the program  I don't need all the functionality of linked lists.

I was trying to do it with double pointers like this, to create the original structure of books.

```
public book** add_bookd(book** books, book* b) {
    static int index = -1;
    int count;
    index++;
    count = index + 1;
    book** books = realloc(books, sizeof(book*)*count);
    books[index] = calloc(1, sizeof(book));
    copy_bookd(books[index], b); //this is just a series of memcopy
                                 //since i have POD data types
   return books;
}
```

I've tried it with a very simple char but I am getting seg faults.

```
char** double_pointer(char** a, char* b) {
    static int index = -1; int count;
    index++;
    count = index + 1;
    a = realloc(a, sizeof(char*)*count);
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        a[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
        a[i] = b;
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
    return a;
}


char** tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    double_pointer(tmp, "a");
    //printf("%s\n",tmp)); //seg faults here
}
```

is this something that would be better implemented with a linked list? Why am I getting seg faults? I mean gdb shows that i crash on that line.

When I print the value of tmp gdb reports

```
p tmp $1 = (char **) 0x0
```

trying to access tmp[0] gdb says can't access memory at 0x0.

Comment: [`public`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251180/in-c-what-does-public-mean-when-put-before-a-global-variable) in C?

Comment: `static int index = -1;` : This is a bad idea. Because it  only can be used as a continuing procedure. In other words, you will not be able to deal with another linked list.

Comment: `tmp` is a `char **` (pointer to a pointer), not the beginning of a null terminated string.

Comment: It seems you have some kind of misconception, but it's hard to tell what that is because you do not present a complete program that demonstrates your problem.  We can help you better if you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: when calling any memory allocation function (malloc, calloc, realloc( always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  When calling `realloc()` do not directly assign the returned value to the target point.  Because if `realloc()` fails (which it can do) then the original point to allocated memory (in this case `a` ) is overlayed/lost.  This results in a memory leak and any following access to `a` is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Rather, use a temp pointer and check that the temp pointer is not NULL before assigning to target pointer

Comment: amongst other problems with the code, this line: `a[i] = b;` in your 'char' example is trying to place a pointer into a char.  Suggest: `a[i] = *b;` so the char where 'b' pointer is placed into the array

Comment: Given the text in the OP, sounds like an array would do what you need. An array supports adding books at the end. If you know the max number of books you'll ever have you can allocate the whole array up front. If not you're code will need to be able to re-allocate the array if it runs out of space..

Answer (score 0):

these lines:

```
book** books = realloc(books, sizeof(book*)*count);
books[index] = calloc(1, sizeof(book));
copy_bookd(books[index], b);
```

are showing some problems, especially regarding the lack of error checking.

Suggest:

```
book* temp = realloc(*books, sizeof(book*)*count);

if( temp != NULL )
{ // then, realloc successful

    *books = temp;
     (*books)[index] = calloc(1, sizeof(book));
     if( (*books)[index] != NULL )
     { // then, calloc successful
         copy_bookd((*books)[index], b);
     }

     else
     {
         // handle calloc failure
     }
}

else
{
    // handle realloc failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking at a possibility to store a number of books, to which you'll probably only add? This can indeed be done with an approach quite similar to what you already have. But let's start from the bottom up:

Basically, somewhere in memory you store an "array" of books, that is several `struct book` in a contiguous memory location. You can point to that array using a pointer to the first book:

```
struct book * books;
```

Somehow, you also need to be able to know where that array ends. The two possibilities I see therefore are to either use a sentinel value (similar to what C strings do with `'\0'`) or to just keep track of the size of the array. I'd choose the later:

```
size_t count;
```

Since you don't want to get lost, we use structured programming techniques and bind these two pieces of information together:

```
struct bookstore {
  struct book * books;
  size_t count;
};
```

In order to work with such a store common operations should be put behind fancy names. This is called abstraction, probably *the* most important thing to do when programming. The device to do this in C is the function. Start off with one to initialise an empty store:

```
char init_store(struct bookstore * store) {
  assert(store != NULL);
  store->count = 0;
  store->books = malloc(0);
  return (store->books == NULL) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

And add its dual, a function to "finish" a store:

```
void finish_store(struct bookstore * store) {
  assert(store != NULL);
  assert(store->books != NULL);
  store->count = 0;
  free(store->books);
  store->books = NULL;
}
```

These functions only operate on already present `struct bookstore` instances. You allocate them either on the stack or the heap (via `malloc` and don't forget to `free`).

Now to the crucial part: Adding a book. For that, you need to enlarge the "array" in order to be able to store a new item in there. This is done using `realloc`. Then you just add the book by copying it to the free place:

```
char add_book(struct bookstore * store, struct book book) {
  assert(store != NULL);
  assert(store->books != NULL);
  struct book * books =
    realloc(store->books, (store->count + 1) * sizeof(struct book));
  if (books == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  books[store->count] = book;
  store->books = books;
  store->count += 1;
  return 1;
}
```

That's how I'd approach this, though there's plenty of room for optimisation. Note that the above code is untested, though.

The approach is basically the same as yours: You'll be working with a pointer to (a struct containing) a pointer to your books. The important difference is that the size gets stored, too. Your code uses a static local variable for that, which essentially limits you to having only a single "list" of books. As an advise: Avoid global or static state like hell.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach keeping track of a number of structs. About the easiest dynamic structure is a *dynamic array of structs*. The same approach for memory management would apply, but you could add another outer struct to help keep the information relative to that one collection of books. E.g. if you had multiple collections you were interested in, you could do something similar to:

```
typedef {
    size_t nbooks;
    size_t allocsz;
    char colname[16];
    struct {
        char* name;
        size_t number;
    } book;
} collection;
```

An approach like this allows for a struct that holds the number of books it contains, its current allocation size, and a unique name for the collection (e.g. *fiction*, *non-fiction*, *etc...*)

You can consider whether something like that adds enough additional data to meet your needs. As for the basic handling of your array of structs, a dynamically declared array is all that it needed. It is then up to you to keep track of the number currently allocated, the number filled, and then to `realloc` when the number filled reaches your limit.

To add a book to your collection, you can do something simple, e.g.:

```
void addbook (book **books, char *name, size_t num, size_t *n, size_t *max)
{
    (*books)[*n].name = strdup (name);
    (*books)[*n].number = num;

    if ( ++(*n) >= *max) {  /* realloc */
        void *tmp = realloc (*books, sizeof **books * 2 * *max);
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc, virtual memory exhausted.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *books = tmp;
        memset (*books + *max, 0, sizeof **books * *max);
        *max *= 2;
    }
}
```

Above the *address* for your array of structs is passed, along with the *book name* and *number* to be added, the current book count, and the current max. `strdup` is used to allocate space for the name, the book number is assigned, and then a check for reallocation is made. That's all there is to it.

A short example of an array approach would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXB = 64 };

typedef struct {
    char* name;
    size_t number;
} book;

void addbook (book **books, char *name, size_t num, size_t *n, size_t *max);

int main (void) {

    book *books = calloc (MAXB, sizeof *books); /* check for error cond */
    char name[MAXB] = "";
    size_t maxb = MAXB, i, idx = 0, len = 0, n = 0, nadd = 0;

    printf ("\n number of books to enter: ");
    while (scanf ("%zu%*c", &nadd) != 1) {
        printf ("  invalid number, try again: ");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nadd; i++) {  /* take input and add to books */
        size_t nlen;
        printf (" enter book title : ");
        while (scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name) != 1) {
            printf ("  invalid name, try again: ");
        }
        printf (" enter book number: ");
        while (scanf ("%zu%*c", &n) != 1) {
            printf ("  invalid number, try again: ");
        }
        addbook (&books, name, n, &idx, &maxb);

        nlen = strlen (name);  /* max length for output formatting */
        if (nlen > len) len = nlen;
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {  /* print the books added */
        printf (" book[%2zu]  %-*s   %zu\n", i, (int)len,
                books[i].name, books[i].number);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)   /* free allocated memory */
        free (books[i].name);
    free (books);

    return 0;
}

void addbook (book **books, char *name, size_t num, size_t *n, size_t *max)
{
    (*books)[*n].name = strdup (name);
    (*books)[*n].number = num;

    if ( ++(*n) >= *max) {  /* realloc */
        void *tmp = realloc (*books, sizeof **books * 2 * *max);
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc, virtual memory exhausted.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *books = tmp;
        memset (*books + *max, 0, sizeof **books * *max);
        *max *= 2;
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_books_single

 number of books to enter: 4
 enter book title : Moby Dick
 enter book number: 23478
 enter book title : Tom Sawyer
 enter book number: 23479
 enter book title : Of mice and men
 enter book number: 23480
 enter book title : Of other flesh & tongue
 enter book number: 23510

 book[ 0]  Moby Dick                 23478
 book[ 1]  Tom Sawyer                23479
 book[ 2]  Of mice and men           23480
 book[ 3]  Of other flesh & tongue   23510
```

Look over the example, and let me know if you have any questions. You can add as many books as your memory can hold. All books are freed on exit.