# Is a return statement always necessary in a c function?

Tags: c, gcc

```
PUBLIC void delset( set )
SET *set;
{
    /* Delete a set created with a previous newset() call. */

    if( set->map != set->defmap )
        free( set->map );
    free( set );

}
```

Do you always have to have a return statement in a c function ? The above function throws the following warning. Notice that I don't have a return statement.

```
src/tools/set.c: In function ‘delset’:
src/tools/set.c:41:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Once I add the `return 0;` the warning goes away. I get the warning even if I just specify `return;`

```
PUBLIC void delset( set )
SET *set;
{
    /* Delete a set created with a previous newset() call. */

    if( set->map != set->defmap )
        free( set->map );
    free( set );

    return 0;
}
```

I am using `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4`

**Edit**

`#   define PUBLIC`

Seems like it is just a marker. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251180/in-c-what-does-public-mean-when-put-before-a-global-variable) seems to explain it better than I can.

```
void delset( set )
SET *set;
{
    /* Delete a set created with a previous newset() call. */

    if( set->map != set->defmap )
        free( set->map );
    free( set );        
}
```

I removed the PUBLIC marker in front of the function and the return line at the bottom. I still get the same error.

```
typedef struct _set_
{
    unsigned char nwords;                                   /* Number of words in map */
    unsigned char compl;                                    /* is a negative true set if true */
    unsigned nbits;                                         /* Number of bits in map */
    _SETTYPE *map;                                          /* Pointer to the map */
    _SETTYPE defmap[ _DEFWORDS ];                           /* The map itself */

} SET;
```

Inclusion of the following header file (`debug.h`) was causing the problem. Not sure which line exactly was causing it.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define PRIVATE
#   define D (x) x
#else
#   define PRIVATE static
#   define D (x)
#endif
#   define PUBLIC

#ifdef MSDOS
#   define MS(x) x 
#   define UX(x)
#   define ANSI
#   define _8086
#else
#   define MS(x)
#   define UX(x) x
#   define O_BINARY 0 /*no binary input mode in UNIX open() */
    typedef long time_t; /* for the VAX, may have to change this */
    typedef unsigned s1ze_t; /* for the VAX, may have to change this. Renamed the type as s1ze_t as stdio.h contains a type of the same name */
    extern char *strdup(); /* You need to supply one. */
#endif

#ifdef ANSI /* If ANSI is defined, put arg lists into */
#   define P(x) x /* function prototypes. */
#   define VA_LIST ... /* and use ellipsis if a variable number of args */
#else
#   define P(x) () /*Otherwise, discard argument lists and translate*/
#   define void char /* void keyword to int. */
#   define VA LIST _a_r_g_s /* don't use ellipsis */
#endif

/* SEG (p) Evaluates to the segment portion of an 8086 address.
 * OFF (p) Evaluates to the offset portion of an 8086 address.
 * PHYS (p) Evaluates to a long holding a physical address
 */

#ifdef _8086
#   define SEG(p) ( ((unsigned *)&(p)) [1] )
#   define OFF(p) ( ((unsigned *)&(p)) [0] )
#   define PHYS(p) (((unsigned long)OFF(p)) + ((unsigned long)SEG(p) << 4))
#else
#   define PHYS(p) (p)
#endif

/* NUMELE (array) Evaluates to the array size in elements
 * LASTELE(array) Evaluates to a pointer to the last element
 * INBOUNDS(array,p) Evaluates to true i f p points into the array.
 * RANGE(a,b,c) Evaluates to true i f a <= b <= c
 * max(a,b) Evaluates to a or b, whichever is larger
 * min (a, b) Evaluates to a or b, whichever is smaller
 *
 * NBITS (type) Returns number of bits in a variable of the indicated
 * type;
 * MAXINT Evaluates to the value of the largest signed integer
 */

#define NUMELE(a)       (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*(a)))
#define LASTELE(a)      ((a) + (NUMELE(a)-1))
#define TOOHIGH(a,p)        ((p) - (a) > (NUMELE(a) - 1))
#define TOOLOW(a,p)         ( (p) - (a) < 0 )
#define INBOUNDS(a,p)       (!(TOOHIGH(a,p) || TOOLOW(a,p))

#define _IS(t, x) (((t)1 << (x)) != 0) /* Evaluate true if the width of a */
                    /* variable of type of t is < x. The !=0 */
                    /* assures that the answer is 1 or 0 */

#define NBITS(t) (4 * (1 + _IS(t, 4) + _IS(t, 8) + _IS(t,12) + _IS(t, 16) + _IS(t,20) + _IS(t,24) + _IS(t,28) + _IS(t,32) ) 


#define MAXINT (((unsigned)~0) >> 1)

#ifndef max
#   define max(a, b)    (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
#ifndef min
#   define min(a,b)     (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
#define RANGE(a,b,c)    ((a) <= (b) && (b) <= (c))
```

Comment: What  is `PUBLIC`?

Comment: How does the pre-processor's output look like?

Comment: It's necessary for non-`void` functions.  If you don't want the function to return a value, declare it to be `void`.  Then control can reach the end of the function without it being an error (and you can also use bare `return` statements).  If the function is non-`void`, then it should always return a value.

Comment: Also, why aren't you using normal function prototypes?  Declaring the arguments after the argument list was phased out in prehistoric times.  Nobody does that anymore.

Comment: Hey Tom, no reason. Just trying to stay true to the book as much as I can. These are helper functions and I wouldn't know whether I copied them well until I use them. If and when they fail, I want to be able to go back and compare it with the code from the book.

Ok, if it is not necessary for non-void functions, is the warning expected ? If so is there a way to hide the warning only for that function ?

Comment: Are you sure that the `}` after `free( set )` is actually line 41 ?

Comment: Hi Marian, I have updated the question with the struct `SET` declaration.

Comment: Hi M.M, yes, `}` is on line 41.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You posted a void function but the compiler messages refer to a non-void function.

Comment: Do you have `#define void` earlier in the code, perhaps?

Comment: Never mind. This apparantly was coming from `#include <tools/debug.h>` Once I removed that line. The warning dissappeared. Although I am not sure what part of that header file was causing that error. I will post the debug.h in the question for reference.

Comment: It sounds as if you ought to consider whether the book your using is fit for its purpose, as it appears to be suggesting things that are now considered somewhat dubious practises.

Comment: Sounds like you are using a book that is over 30 years old, before `void` and prototypes were added to C. Maybe consider getting more up-to-date learning materials

Comment: I am new to C and `Compiler Design In C` by Holub book seems to spoon feed, which I like :-). And he has tons and tons of code which is also sweet. Would you suggest any `Compiler design` books for non comp-sci major and a C newbie ?

Comment: Your problem is here:: `#   define void char /* void keyword to int. */`

Comment: Now when you use `void` as return type, the compiler complains because you are not returning any char value from your function.

Comment: The problem is this line: `#   define void char /* void keyword to int. */`. It's some sort of compatibility with ancient compilers that triggered because you didn't `#define ANSI` (which you don't normally have to do, it's just how that ancient debug library works). Consider learning from something more recent like [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/).

Comment: Hey Abhineet, you are right. When I return `NULL` it complains that I am returning a char value. So I had to cast it based on the method return type.

Comment: For the time being, you can just use `#define ANSI` (be aware of all the side-effects it may incur on your code). Always better to learn the latest version of language as you are already committing so much of energy and time. So, better use it wisely.

Comment: Yeah, I just commented out the `ifdef` for now since I am using `GCC`. I will try to find newer books in c. Thankyou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A return statement is not necessary.

If your function has a non-void return type, and you don't return a value, and the caller uses the return value, then it causes undefined behaviour.

The compiler gives a warning because your function has a non-void return type, and it thinks you might have meant to return a value but forgotten.

The code you posted doesn't correspond to the compiler message, unless `PUBLIC` is defined to something strange.

Comment: I bet there is a way to disable the warning for that one function and not globally. This way the compiler will show me the warning at other locations. Something like `@SuppressWarnings` in java.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun fixing the mistake would be better than suppressing the warning.

Comment: Not sure the warning is coming from `PUBLIC`. The warning is still there after I removed it and the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You will always get a warning if the return-type of a function is not `void`.

If you want to stop the execution of a void- type function (even though there still might be instructions to be executed) use `return;` .

Hope I helped !

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have some basic syntax misunderstandings, but if you just insert "void" before your function name (SET), the compiler will understand that the function returns nothing and the warning will be alleviated.